# How to code related tables for inserting new record core data

Tags: core-data

I have 4 entities for a core data database. The first entity is the master. The other 3 entities are related on a one to many relationship, meaning that the master will have only one record each but the other related entities could have multiple records for each in the master entity.

I have no problems saving a new record in the master. What I don't understand is how to save records in the related entities. I know how to set the values of the fields. That's not the problem. What I don't know how to set is the related fields which are NSSets.

I'll be happy to provide you with additional information such as code if you can tell me what you need to see.

Comment: I wish someone would help me. I have screen capture images of the tables, how they're set up, and the error message I'm getting but I see no way to even post those images. I've been stuck on this problem for 3 days now.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple. When generating your `NSManagedObject` subclasses, you will notice auto-generated methods for to-many relationships similar to this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) Other *relationship;

-(void) addRelationshipObject:(Other*)value;
-(void) removeRelationshipObject:(Other*)value;
-(void) addRelationship:(NSSet*)values;
-(void) removeRelationship:(NSSet*)values;
```

Simply use those to insert/delete one or more objects in the relationship.

Comment: Thanks, I understand all of that, but that still doesn't answer my question. I don't know what I'm suppose to put in the NSSet fields. Do I first set the values for the other fields of the entity and then add the entity to the NSSet of the related entity? That's what I don't understand, what goes in this NSSet?

Comment: Yeah, thanks for everybody's help, ha. I figured it out for myself but don't care to share the answer since no one seemed interested in helping me out.

Comment: Why is that? I gave an answer. The answer is complete in the sense that you *do not have to set the inverse relationship*.